# Last page in \AddToHook{enddocument/end} not displayed

Tags: lthooks

The following MWE gives only two pages, the third one not being displayed. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{enddocument/end}{
  1
  \newpage
  2
  \newpage
  3
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to add typeset output in `enddocument/end`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I know that :) But the strange thing is that this typeset output is still displayed and, furthermore, not entirely.

Comment: you are not triggering the output on the last page. `3\par\penalty -10000` will work (or a \newpage).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed! In any case, strange edge case :)